# Nginx root to one file in a directory and deny all the others

Tags: nginx

I have **one** app folder with **many dev files**, among them there is an **index.html** file.

I would like nginx to serve this index.html **only**:

```
domain.com/ -> app/index.html
```

and `deny all` the other files/subfolders.

Here is what I have right now, but it works only for **domain.com/index.html**:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name domain.com;

        root /home/app;

        location / {
                deny all;
                location ~ \.(html)$ {
                        allow all;
                }
        }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to structure this, but an exact match location is useful to extract a single URI. I use an empty directory (`/var/empty`) if the default is to deny access:

```
root /var/empty;
location = / {
    root /home/app;
    rewrite ^ /index.html break;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.